# Why i get alert : "This page has expired" in laravel livewire upon logging back in in?

Tags: php-7, laravel-7, laravel-livewire

I created a step-by-step form using Laravel Livewire, following this tutorial: [here](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-9-livewire-wizard-multi-step-form-tutorialexample.html).

However, I'm experiencing some issues when logging in after logging out, when I submit the form I get a alert:

> "This page has expired".

Interestingly, when I run `php artisan optimize:clear`, the alert disappears. Does anyone know the reason behind this behavior?

[image: Alert image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to add this to `VerifyCsrfToken` Middleware:

```
 protected $except = [
         'livewire/*',
     ];
```